# Extract to an OCaml file by using "Recursive Extraction" in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-extraction

I want to extract a function `foo` in `Coq` to an `OCaml` file. Because my real function have to use the `Recursive Extraction`, when I run a program it output the extracted OCaml code on the `cmd`. But I would like to output it to a file, for example: `foo.ml`

```
Recursive Extraction foo.
```

When I tried:

```
Recursive Extraction "foo.ml" foo.
```

or `Recursive Extraction foo "foo.ml"`

I got an error: `Syntax error: "." expected after [vernac:command] (in [vernac_aux]).`

My question is: Am I able to extract the function `foo` to a file by using the `Recursive Extraction` syntax? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual (http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual027.html), `Extraction "foo.ml" foo` will extract `foo` and recursively all its dependencies into `foo.ml`, i.e. you don't need `Recursive` in that case, it is only used for extraction on stdout.